# show this summation hold in term of integral

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, summation

i can show $\sum |x|^2=\int_a^b|f(x)|^2dx$ in term of integral, or this one  $|\sum x\overline y|^2=|\int_a^bf(x)\overline {g(x)}dx|^2$ but i don't know how to show this one $\sum_{i}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}|(x_i\overline y_j-x_j\overline y_i)|^2$ in term of integral

$\sum_{i}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}|(x_i\overline y_j-x_j\overline y_i)|^2=?$

Comment: What are the functions $f,g$, and the numbers $a,b$? What are $x,y$ in your sums? What are you summing over in $\sum |x|^2$?

Comment: How was this question upvoted? As it's written, it makes no sense to me. I downvoted.